# The long long int is not supporting the multiplication of larger number

Tags: c++

I am trying to execute a simple long multiplication but it is not showing the correct the output.
here is the sample code

```
'''
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    long long int c=100000*90000;
    cout<<c;
    return 0;
}
'''
```

cout of variable c is: 410065408

I dont know why it is displaying the garbage value instead of 9000000000.

Comment: This code is multiplying two ints, obtain an int, and then convert it to a long long

Comment: I.e. I don't suppose you tried `100000LL*90000LL` or similar?

Comment: Enable warnings to catch this. Modern compilers will [warn](https://godbolt.org/z/6v4avn) even without warnings.

Answer (score 5):

On a platform with a 32 bit `int`, `100000` and `90000` are `int` types (Note that on platforms with a 16 bit `int` they would be `long` types and a similar analysis to what I present here would apply to a 32 bit `long`.)

Hence you are multiplying two `int` types. You are overflowing the `int`, with undefined results, although it's no coincidence that 9000000000 - 410065408 is a multiple of 2<sup>32</sup> (but don't rely on that since it's little more than a manifestation of undefined behaviour).

```
100000LL * 90000
```

is a fix.

Comment: Basically I have generate random numbers (which can be long as 100000) to fill the array and calculate the maximum pair wise product.

Answer (score 3):

The type of `100000` is (probably <sup>1</sup>) `int` (on your system). The type of `90000` (probably) is `int` (on your system). You are multiplying two `int` objects. `int` is guaranteed to represent numbers up to 32'767. On modern x86 systems it can represent up to 2'147'483'647. Those maximums are less than 9'000'000'000. As such, the behaviour of the program is undefined.

The fact that you initialise a `long long` using this overflowed `int` is irrelevant to the result. You must perform the multiplication on `long long` objects to get a 64 bit (at least) multiplication.

---

<sup>1</sup> Assuming those numbers are representable as `int` on your system, which it is on modern x86 systems. It could be `long` on some systems.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: I still maintain my conjecture that the majority of systems running C and C++ programs at the time of my writing this have a 16 bit `int` type.